# Transition the text inside a div

Tags: jquery, animation, fade, jquery-animate, transition

I have a table of line items with amounts and the user can select or deselect items.  I have an element on the page that when a change occurs in the selection(s), a total is computed for the selected items.

Here's what my function looks like that sums the values.

```
function ComputeTotalPayment() {
    var sum = 0;

    $.each($("[id^='payment-amount-']"), function () {
        //...compute sum here
    });

    if ($('amount-total'))
        $('#amount-total').text('$' + sum.toFixed(2));  //display
}
```

When I change the text of `amount-total` (a div), is there a way to get the numbers to fade from the old value into the new value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
$("#amount-total").fadeOut(function(){ $(this).text("test").fadeIn(); })
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon changing the text, you could first fade the text, then make the content change, then fade it back in

Comment: Not quite the effect I was looking for, but it is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a clone of the dom object, position in the same spot as old one then fade out the old while fading in the new one then delete the old one.